# connect to MS Access accdb file on Windows Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, ado.net, windows-server-2008

In my ASP.NET application I have `ftpdata` folder, there is an MS Access 2010 file e.g. `somename.accdb`.

On my local computer (Win XP), there is no problem to connect with OleDb to this file and read write datas into and from tables.

But on server (Windows Server 2008),  I cannot connect to the same file like on localhost.
Can you help me, please, where problem could be?

Comment: May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420778/configure-asp-net-to-use-x86-on-x64-windows also 64 bit ACE drivers: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found solution of problem.

There was not installed 2010 Data Connectivity Components on the server.

Comment: This is what solved my problem too.  I could not install the 64bit version because I only had office 2003, so I installed the 32bit version, and now my webpages can read .accdb files.

Answer (score 0):

The windows user that your application pool is running in does probably not have read access to the directory/file

Comment: How about the x86 / x64 driver difference?

Comment: Hi citronas, thanks for reply! I also think problem is here. But how should I set security access to this directory? I tried set security as Everyone, but it's not funtional solution.

Comment: @eridanix: Look in the IIS manager in the settings dialog for the ApplicationPool that your WebApplication is running in. There is property called UserIdentity for named somehow similar. You can specify a user there. I usually use "NetworkService"

Answer (score 0):

You need either direct access through the file system or SMB networking access (via a share defined on the server). If the FTP folder has an SMB share name, use that to get to it, but it's likely not shared (since it's purpose is for FTP access, not SMB access).

Answer (score 0):

Installing the 2010 Data Connectivity Drivers does not seem to work, what worked for me was to set the corresponding website application pool in IIS to enable 32-Bit applications.

[Official Microsoft Reference:](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/using-classic-asp-with-microsoft-access-databases-on-iis)